# sending request to postman and it is giving an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, postman

I am trying to send the request to postman but it is giving me an error.The nodemon is working and the server is running in the terminal

index.server.js file

```
//jshint esversion:6
const express = require("express");
const env = require("dotenv");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();
//routes
const userRoutes = require('./routes/user');
env.config();


mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_DB_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_DB_PASSWORD}@cluster0.igfgf61.mongodb.net/${process.env.MONGO_DB_DATABASE}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,{
    // useNewUrlParser: true,
    // useUnifiedTopology:true,
    // useCreateIndex : true
}).then(() => {
    console.log("database connected");
});


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use('./api/', userRoutes);

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`server is running successfully on ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

routes/user.js file

```
//jshint esversion:6
const express = require("express");
const { signup } = require("../controller/user");
const router = express.Router();
router.post('/signup', signup);
router.post('/signin', (req, res) => {
     
    
 });

module.exports = router
```

models/user.js file

```
//jshint esversion:6
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        min: 3,
        max: 20
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        min: 3,
        max: 20
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        unique: true,
        index: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    hash_password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['user', 'admin'],
        default: 'user'
    },
    contactNumber: {type: String},
    profilePicture: {type: String},
}
,{timestamps: true});

userSchema.virtual('password')
.set(function(password){
this.hash_password=bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10);
});

userSchema.methods= {
    authenticate: function(password){
        return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.hash_password);
    }
}
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

controller/user.js file

```
//jshint esversion:6
const User = require("../models/user");
exports.signup =(req, res) => {
User.findOne({email: req.body.email})
    .exec((error, user) => {
        if(user) return res.status(400).json({
            message: 'user already registered'
        });
        const {
            firstName,
            lastName,
            email,
            password
        } =req.body;
        const _user = new User({ 
            firstName, 
            lastName, 
            email, 
            password, 
            username: Math.random().toString()
        });
       _user.save((error, data) => {
          if(error){
            return res.status(400).json({
                message: 'something went wrong'
            });
          }
          if(data){
             return res.status(201).json({
                            message: 'user created succesfully'
                        });
                    }
       });

    });
}
```

when i am trying to post request it is giving me an error. what should i do?
this is the request i made in postman and it is giving me an error(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qsn5V.png)

Answer (score 1):

In your index.server.js instead of "./api/" use "/api"

```
app.use("/api", userRoutes)
```